# MVC HttpPost Data Paramater is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been trying to figure this issue out since Yesterday to no luck. Basically here is the code.

```
    public ActionResult AddFolder()
    {
        return View(new Folder());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddFolder(Folder f)
    {

        if (f != null)
        {

            FolderDAL folderObject = new FolderDAL();
            folderObject.Add(f);
            folderObject.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("AddFolder", f);

    }
```

The [HttpPost] Add(Folder f) seems to be null ? I have no idea why. There could be one issue that is that the Models (Entities) are in a different assembly which is referenced, but why would it be null?

if I made a Models folder (In the MVC Project) with a Folder class then this would work, but it does not work when referencing the entities from an assembly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update

**View Code**

```
 @model uk.BusinessEntities.Folder
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddFolder";
}

<h2>AddFolder</h2>

@Html.BeginForm()
(
<div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FolderName)
        @Html.EditorFor(e => e.FolderName)
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
)
```

Comment: What does the view look like?

Comment: Just for testing purpose, how about changing the parameter in the post function to Formcollection instead of Folder?  Then you can check breakpoint and see if the FormCollection variable contains your values.

Comment: Maybe the value names could be translated differently if it is from a different assembly.  For instance, the FolderName would be translated to the variable name as "BusinessEntities.Folder.FolderName" similar to using ViewModels within forms.  Just a guess  :)

Comment: I just used FormCollection and it breaks on it I get the keys which is "FolderName" but no values. I have no idea why the Folder class throws a null reference exception..

Comment: I just passed in a string folderName as parameter and that seems to work with the value of FolderName, so I am guessing it something to do with the Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scratching my heading for a day and cursing my screen I have finally solved the issue. The validate method caused the issue since it was returning null.

```
public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       return null
    }
```